# AWK: print $i returns nothing

Tags: bash, printing, awk

`$file` is a csv (tab-delimited) with 59 cols and 64 rows. Column 1 is always a string and cols 2+ are always an integer (except once when the value is `NULL`).

```
cat ${file} | while read line 
    do awk -F'\t' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i "." }';
    done;
```

Outputs:

```
Excellent   .
Good    .
…
```

And yet switching `$i` to `$2` works:

```
Excellent   29.
Good    7.
…
```

Why??

**EDIT**:

```
#lines 1 & 2 from data.csv (columns truncated for brevity):
Excellent   29  54  47  46  38  22  50
Good    7   14  27  24  26  36  20

#reform.sh
file=$1;
awk -F'\t' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i; }' ${file};
```

Still behaves/returns like the previous.

**RESOLUTION**:

The approved answer does provide the proper output from AWK. After restarting my Terminal application, the script performed as described. I was not able to determine the cause of the Terminal app issue.

Comment: Some shells and awk versions work strangely with `\t` in single quotes. Try using `"\t"`.

Comment: @polm23 thanks. i don't know why, but I quit/re-opened Termainal and it just started working…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're mistaken. The script as you have it doesn't output anything intelligent <sup>(a)</sup> because, while you're attempting to read each line into `$line`, you're not actually giving them to `awk`.

You can get rid of the superfluous (and incorrect) loop with something like:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i "." }' ${file}
```

as shown in the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'A 1 2
...> B 3 4
...> C 5 6' >qq.in

pax> cat qq.in
A 1 2
B 3 4
C 5 6

pax> awk -F' ' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 " " $i "." }' qq.in
A 1.
A 2.
B 3.
B 4.
C 5.
C 6.
```

As you can see (although I'm using spaces rather than tabs), this gives you the output you desire.

---

In response to your assertion that it's *still* not working, I'm afraid I have to beg to differ. The following transcript (with tabs) shows that it works as advertised.

```
pax> cat qq.in
Excellent   29      54      47      46      38      22      50
Good        7       14      27      24      26      36      20

pax> awk -F'\t' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i; }' qq.in
Excellent   29
Excellent   54
Excellent   47
Excellent   46
Excellent   38
Excellent   22
Excellent   50
Good        7
Good        14
Good        27
Good        24
Good        26
Good        36
Good        20
```

If it's not actually working in your environment, that's a different issue. You may have a buggy `awk` or any other number of reasons why it would fail.

For a start, figure out what version of `awk` and the operating system you're using, such as with:

```
awk --version
uname -a
```

---

<sup>(a):</sup> It does actually output *something,* but almost certainly not what you'd expect. Let's actually look at what happens in reality. Consider the following transcript which is similar to your original:

```
pax> ( echo 1; echo 2; echo 3 ) | while read line ; do
...>     awk '{print "[" $0 "]"}'
...> done
[2]
[3]
```

Now that looks rather strange, it appears to be throwing away the first line.

The reason for this is the disconnect between the `while` and the `awk`. The `while` reads the first line from standard input and assigns it to `$line`, then executes the body of the `do..done` section.

That body is an `awk` with no input file, hence *it takes its input from standard input!*

That means it will "suck up" the rest of your standard input stream and process it.

Then, it will return to the `while` loop but, with no more data on standard input, it will finish. It's perhaps better illustrated with:

```
pax> ( echo 1; echo 2; echo 3 ) | while read line ; do
...>     echo "read: $line"
...>     awk '{print "awk:  " $0}'
...> done
read: 1
awk:  2
awk:  3
```

If you actually *connect* the `while` and the `awk` with the `echo "$line" |` section below, you'll see it works properly:

```
pax> ( echo 1; echo 2; echo 3 ) | while read line ; do
...>     echo "$line" | awk '{print "[" $0 "]"}'
...> done
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

Of course, it makes little sense to break apart your input into lines and send them to `awk` one at a time, when `awk` is perfectly capable of handling multiple lines one at a time on its own.

So the single-line `awk` command shown in the first code block of this answer is still a better way to do it.

Comment: Oh! `${file}` (or `FILE`) is input! I thought it was the path to send the output. Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation of the while+awk does make sense (but `$i` is still not returning any value)

Comment: I had quit Terminal and when I re-opened it to run `uname -a` and tried running the script again, it just started working >:O Nothing changed in reform.sh or the data.csv. What the hell…

Comment: btw thanks and sorry for the run-around. I think there might be something wrong with my Terminal application (installed a security update today).

Comment: re: `while you're reading each line into $line, you're not actually giving that to awk`.  Not quite.  The `while read` will read the first line of input, `awk` will consume all of the others, and the loop terminates after one iteration (`awk` never sees the first line of the input.)

Comment: @William, that should be clear from the (a) bit at the bottom. The lines being read by `read` are _not_ being given to `awk` though, as you say, `awk` is stealing the rest of stdin. But I'll change it to read "attempting to read" since that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
awk -F$'\t' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i "." }' FILE
```

instead of all the not needed pipes.

Comment: thanks! Didn't realise before that `FILE` was input (thought it was AWK's way of sending output, like with `>>`)

Comment: btw, I copied that (and replaced `FILE` with `${file}`), but `$i` still returns nothing and $2 returns as expected.

Comment: If you have nothing, put some liens of the CSV and the script here.

Comment: I added some lines from the csv and the script I posted under the EDIT is the contents of reform.sh, which I call like this: `$> . reform.sh data.csv`

Comment: Maybe you see tabs where there's only spaces ?!

Comment: They're tabs: I did a regex search for `\t` on the file, and it found the whitespaces. Then I did a search for a space character and it gave me an alert that the pattern was not found. (btw, stackoverflow converts tabs to spaces). Also I would think AWK would freak out if I specified a delimited that doesn't exist in the source/file.

Comment: If you specify a delimiter not in the file awk will just treat the whole line as one field.